# Cannot delete secure cookie?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I cant delete cookies ,it works sometimes (How it can be possible?) but if it begin to stick with not deleting bug it never will work again.I used mobile to see this and I cant delete cookie on mobile.
Codes look like this:

```
setcookie("cookie_name",$value,strtotime('+4year'),"/",null,null,true);
```

When I delete it I use below:

```
setcookie("cookie_token",'',strtotime('-4year'),"/",null,null,true);
```

I use also this to be sure:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
        $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
        foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
            $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
            $name = trim($parts[0]);
            //databaseden poza bilersen poz ele
            setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
            setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
        }
    }
    session_destroy();
    $session = isset($_SESSION) ? $_SESSION : '';
```

Comment: have you tried javascript to delete those cookies??

Comment: don't use relative times for cookie expiry. that depends on the client's clock being accurate. while a 4 year difference isn't likely, just use time `1` for expiry. Anyone who's still in 1970 shouldn't be expecting much of anything to work properly on their computer.

Comment: @MarcB I used it like this:setcookie("cookie_name", '', 1, '/');But not worked.Have another option?

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya it is not posiible delete secure cookie with javascript

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use `unset` function? I mean something like: `unset($_COOKIE['cookieName'])`.

Comment: unset($_COOKIE['cookieName']) is not working and it is not way to delete cookies

Comment: $_COOKIE is essentially read-only. Any writes to it do **NOT** trigger a new cookie header to the client. you HAVE to use `setcookie()` to modify the cookie client-side.

Comment: that has nothing to do with the above being completely wrong. changing $_COOKIE contents will have ZERO effect on what's stored in the client.

Comment: @MarcB Yes sure,I know this is impossible to delete cookies with unset but I want to learn that why setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/'); is not working